# Get the closest td of particular td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to add the table rows dynamically ,such that id of every element of row should be one more than the ids of  tds of previous row.,like if previous row has tds with ids a7,b7,c7 next row will have tds with a8,b8,c8 and so on

```js
var rowCount=0;
function createit(){

rowCount++;
var tds=$("#addrowtd").closest('tr').children().each((a)=>{
//how to get the ids of tds here
console.log(a);

});// this outputs addrowtd ,how to get a2 ,b2 and c2 of this row
//console.log(tds)
 var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
//I want to increment the each id and then add to the respective field like below
        cols += '<td id="a3"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name' + rowCount + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td id="b3"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="mail' + rowCount + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td id="c3"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="phone' + rowCount + '"/></td>';

  cols += '<td id="addrowtd" colspan="5" style="text-align: left;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " onclick="createit()" id="addrow" >Add Row</button></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("#myTable").append(newRow);
$("#addrowtd").remove();//removig the previous one

}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gmail</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-4" id="a2">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-4" id="b2">
                <input type="mail" name="mail"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3" id="c2">
                <input type="text" name="phone"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td id="addrowtd" colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
            <button type="button" onclick="createit()" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" >Add Row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
   
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you mean "previous sibling" when you say "closest". You should consider using a `data-` attribute to hold the number rather than parsing an id...

Comment: Umm yes right  ,I create a new row every time so I want the ids of all the tds except in which that button is

Comment: Why does your static table content start with ids using 2 rather than 0 or 1?  Also, why ids?  Why not classes, with values that actually make sense?

Comment: I was just exploring may be lol @Taplar

Comment: Note that you should remove the previous `td` with the id before adding the new one with the same id, or just keep it there and insert the new cells before it.

Comment: Its like I want to add a new row ,with the <td>'s having respective ids from previous row ,plus one ,like if previous row has a1 ,b1,c1 then next will be a2,b2 ,c2 and so on

Comment: In the existing table, your `td`s have ids, but in the ones you're creating in script, the `input`s have the ids.

Comment: That's not stating why you need that.  You can use contextual lookups with classes and bypass this whole issue.  You haven't stated what issue you are trying to fix.  This is sounding like an https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery, increment id number when dynamically appending elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700005/jquery-increment-id-number-when-dynamically-appending-elements)

Comment: @HereticMonkey updated my question

Comment: Could you not just give the `tr` an id and then use class names for the `td`s? Why does each cell need a unique id?

Comment: This data is coming from database ,every id represents particular value of table column

Comment: That's a very insecure way of displaying the data.  If you are relying on the ids to relate directly to elements in the database, all a user has to do is inspect the page, change ids, and suddently your data is mismatching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this helps ,I have printed all the ids of td in the row except the last one

```js
var rowCount=0;
function createit(){

rowCount++;
let tdarray=[];
var tds=$("#addrowtd").closest('tr').children().not(':last').each((column, td)=>{
tdarray.push($(td).attr('id'));
//how to get the ids of tds here
console.log($(td).attr('id'));

});// this outputs addrowtd ,how to get a2 ,b2 and c2 of this row
//console.log(tds)
 var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
//I want to increment the each id and then add to the respective field like below
        cols += '<td id="a3"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name' + rowCount + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td id="b3"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="mail' + rowCount + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td id="c3"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="phone' + rowCount + '"/></td>';

  cols += '<td id="addrowtd" colspan="5" style="text-align: left;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " onclick="createit()" id="addrow" >Add Row</button></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("#myTable").append(newRow);
$("#addrowtd").remove();//removig the previous one

}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gmail</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-4" id="a2">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-4" id="b2">
                <input type="mail" name="mail"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-3" id="c2">
                <input type="text" name="phone"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td id="addrowtd" colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
            <button type="button" onclick="createit()" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" >Add Row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
   
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified you code in one line to get the last `tr` from the table and get its `id`, then increment it .
`var tds = $('#myTable').children()[1].lastElementChild.firstElementChild.getAttribute('id');` this is what I did. may be helpful. please take a look at the snippet. to see the `id` change please use developer tool.

```js
var rowCount = 0;

function createit() {
  rowCount++;
  var tds = $('#myTable').children()[1].lastElementChild.firstElementChild.getAttribute('id'); 
  //debugger;
  tds = +tds.match(/\d/g).join('')+1;
  console.log(`new id number ${tds}`)
  var newRow = $("<tr>");
  var cols = "";
  //I want to increment the each id and then add to the respective field like below
  cols += '<td id="a'+tds+'"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name' + rowCount + '"/></td>';
  cols += '<td id="b'+tds+'"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="mail' + rowCount + '"/></td>';
  cols += '<td id="c'+tds+'"><input type="text"  class="form-control" name="phone' + rowCount + '"/></td>';

  cols += '<td id="addrowtd" colspan="5" style="text-align: left;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " onclick="createit()" id="addrow" >Add Row</button></td>';
  newRow.append(cols);
  $("#myTable").append(newRow);
  $("#addrowtd").remove(); //removig the previous one

}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Gmail</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-4" id="a2">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-4" id="b2">
          <input type="mail" name="mail" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-3" id="c2">
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td id="addrowtd" colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
          <button type="button" onclick="createit()" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">Add Row</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I am actually looking to get the ids of all tds in which add button is ,suppose initially its in first so the tds have id a2,b2,c2 and then next time it will be with a3 ,b3 ,c3 .This a2 b2 c2 are from database and I don't know them

Comment: @ron no matter what the first td id is, it will check for the last tr in the table - so when a2 b2 c2 or a1 b1 c1 or if a5 b5 c5 is in the first row - it will take the id and remove charactor from it, that is removes a from it then get the number and adds 1 to it. try giving another number - that is a6 b6 c6 - it will print a7 b7 c7 for the next row.  do some unit test and report if you have any issue -  i will try to reolve those issues